# TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, create-react-app

```
  componentDidMount() {
    window.initMap = this.initMap
    ((doc, script) => {
        const element = doc.getElementsByTagName(script)[0];
        const fjs =element;
        let js = doc.createElement(script);
        js.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${this.props.mapKey}&callback=initMap`
        if (fjs && fjs.parentNode) {
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
          } else {
            doc.head.appendChild(js)
          }
    })(document, 'script')
}

initMap = () =>{

        let uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
        let map = new window.google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});


}
```

i am dynamically creating a script tag to load the google function and assigning the global initMap function to the  local function when i am running this  i am getting cannot read property maps of undefiend 
can anybody help me what wrong i am doing?

Comment: is there a reason why you are creating the script tag dynamically?

Comment: @Sagivb.g the map key comes from the api from the backend so i need to create dynamic script

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code runs before the script loads.
There are already open source project that implement Google Maps out there but if you still want to implement it by your own then you can use [scriptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scriptjs). This package lets you import the resource and run functionality when its loaded. No need for a script tag in this case.

Running example:

```js
class GoogleMap extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.google || !window.google.maps) {
      const { googleKey } = this.props;
      // require is not working inside stackoverflow snippets
      // we are using a cdn for scriptjs, you can use npm
      //const $script = require(`scriptjs`);
      $script(
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=${googleKey}`,
        this.handleGoogleLoad
      );
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const { position } = this.props;
    if (prevProps.position !== position) {
      this.map && this.map.setCenter(position);
      this.marker && this.marker.setPosition(position);
    }
  }

  handleGoogleLoad = () => {
    const { position } = this.props;
    this.map = new window.google.maps.Map(this.mapRef, {
      scaleControl: true,
      center: null,
      zoom: 10
    });
    this.marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
      map: this.map,
      position: position
    });

    this.map.setCenter(position);
    this.marker.setPosition(position);
  };

  render() {
    return <div style={{ height: "350px" }} ref={ref => (this.mapRef = ref)} />;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { lat: 40.741895, lng: -73.989308, googleKey: "" };

  onInputChange = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ [target.name]: target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { lat, lng, googleKey } = this.state;
    const position = { lat: Number(lat), lng: Number(lng) };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>
          <label>Paste google key </label>
          <input
            name="googleKey"
            value={googleKey}
            onChange={this.onInputChange}
          />
          <hr />
          <div>Change coords</div>
          <input name="lat" value={lat} onChange={this.onInputChange} />
          <input name="lng" value={lng} onChange={this.onInputChange} />
        </div>
        <hr />
        {googleKey ? (
          <GoogleMap position={position} googleKey={googleKey} />
        ) : (
          <div>Missing google key</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/script.js/2.5.9/script.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```